# How to vertically center align icon inside table header

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic table, with dynamic no of column and rows... In table header, I need to fix sort icon vertically center.. Even table header text size is dynamic and no of lines keeps growing...  how to vertically align sort icon while text size keeps increases?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KrishnaAnanthi/6gqn1Lxp/12/)

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th><div class='filter-container header-container'> <div class='header-text'>  Firstname Firstname Firstnam eFirstnam eFirstname Firstname Firstname Firstname Firstname</div><div class='icon-right'> <span    class= "fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span   class= "fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div></div></th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.filter-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.sort-icon {
  float: right !important;
  clear: right;
  height: 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: which `.header-text` css class is actually relevant to your code? any particular reason you can't merge them together?

Comment: Is there a css table solution for this without using flexbox?

Answer (score 4):

Use a wrapper of the entire table header cell contents. Inside it, use two elements. The text and the icon:

```
<th>
  <div class="aligner">
    <div class="text">any text here can be as long as you want</div>
    <div class="icon">your icon here</div>
  </div>
</th>
```

and use:

```
th .aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Obviously, both aligned elements need to have equal vertical `padding`, `border` and `margin`s.

---

Using the example you just added, here's a starter: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/h94yen82/

I removed your styles for the sorter and added:

```
.header-container {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sort-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but unfortunately does not result in pure semantic HTML

Comment: @josh, we don't know the semantics of this HTML (the icon could be a display of current order or it could be a control to change the current order). Which is why I've used elements devoid of HTML semantics. Feel free to write an essay about how the HTML structure of a table header should look like.

Comment: You are correct, it is very difficult to make meaningful comments on the semantics here since we don't know the content. Personally I was put off by the `.aligner` wrapper, since this seems by definition a non-semantic element.

Comment: Since you can't change the `display` property of a table cell (it's dedicated to its table role), cell wrappers are very common in HTML. I don't see a better fit for such a wrapper than `<div>`. Do you? A `<span>` would be my next option, but it would require some extra CSS to make sure it covers the entire width of the cell at all times.

Comment: Besides, you seem to believe using `<div>`s is non pure from HTML semantics point of view. That's wrong. A `<div>` is a *division*. In other words, a part. It can be anything. Semantically, it means: unknown semantics. Which is a the correct semantics when you build dynamic content and you don't know what it's going to be used for.

Comment: Pointing out a problem is not going to make people listen to you. Fixing the problem in a better way might. It largely depends on the ratio between the importance of the problem and the effort required to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Quick/simply fix, add this to `.icon-right`:

```
.icon-right {
    ...
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: relative;
}
```

### Edit

Since you want to apply this to all columns, try this:

```
.icon-right {/* Add this new class */
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}

th {/* Add this new class */
    position: relative;
}

.filter-container {
    ...
    /*position: relative;*/ /* remove this line */
    ...
}
```

Try it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv63tu4j/).

Comment: this works for me.. but why are we substracting 8px? can u explain this piece of code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KrishnaAnanthi/6gqn1Lxp/18/   when i add to all column it breaks

Comment: @user2900572 `calc()` allows to set dynamic value. So it's basically setting the top to 50% (so it will be in the middle, but this means the top part of the arrows are in the middle), then -8px (so push it up a little to be perfectly in the middle). -8px is half of the height of the icon.

Answer (score 1):

you can use transform to make div vertically align

```
.icon-right{
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

Comment: Amazing that this is the only answer on the whole internet that actually works

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56y4wmkz/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .header-container {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: add a js fiddle link.

Comment: its not in the center.. see the gap on top and bottom

Comment: actually these are in center position when you inspect you notice that spans are in exact center positioned , arrows are in after and before sudo elements of span thats why gap difference appears... i hope you under stand it...

Comment: yeah its not center aligned vertically

Answer (score 0):

Try These properties I think it's useful for you.

```
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icon-right {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.filter-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px !important;
 margin: 0px !important;
}
.header-container {
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.header-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.header-text {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.header-text {
 width: 90%;
 float: left;
 text-align: start;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 text-align: left;
}
.sort-icon {
 float: right !important;
 clear: right;
  height: 1px !important;
}

 .header-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

.icon-right {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th><div class='filter-container header-container'> <div class='header-text'>  Firstname Firstname Firstnam eFirstnam eFirstname Firstname Firstname Firstname Firstname</div>
      <div class='icon-right'> <span    class= "fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span   class= "fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div></div></th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is my code pen link

https://codepen.io/arshiyakhanam_786/pen/JzyvKe

Answer (score 0):

Almost answer set height of two icons is 0px or 1px to make two icons is nearly, so cannot click to sort. I think you should use another icon (or image) width distance to top and bottom rational (like `fa-caret`). How about this?

https://jsfiddle.net/2merngco/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but using absolute position worked for me!

```html
<th>
 Title <span class="sort-icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span>
</th>
```

```css
.sort-icon {
    position: absolute;
}
```